# Convert an ff POSIXct vector to an ff numeric vector

Tags: r, posixct, ff

I am trying to convert an **ff** vector with *POSIXct* entries to an **ff** *numeric* vector, containing the respective number of seconds since the origin 01-01-1970.

`x = as.ff(as.POSIXct(c("2014-06-30 00:01:27 BST", "2014-06-30 00:02:17 BST")))`

The 'natural' `as.numeric(x)` does not work, yielding: `numeric(0)`.

`as.ff(as.numeric(x[]))` works, yielding

`ff (open) double length=2 (2)
       [1]        [2] 
1398898887 1398898937`

which is the desirable outcome. Albeit, it involves the ram object `x[]`. Is there a way to achieve the above result employing ff objects only (i.e. not intermediating the ram equivalent of the ff vector)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require(ff)
x = as.ff(as.POSIXct(c("2014-06-30 00:01:27 BST", "2014-06-30 00:02:17 BST")))
## Either clone it (creates a duplicate of the ff file)
done <- clone(x, ramclass = "numeric", ramattribs = list())
done[]
[1] 1404079287 1404079337
attr(,"class")
[1] "numeric"

## Or just modify the ramclass and ramattribs (see ?virtual: virtual(x))
virtual(x)$ramclass <- NULL
virtual(x)$ramattribs <- NULL
x[]
[1] 1404079287 1404079337

## And wrap this up in your own function
```